Incidence axioms in Euclidean space and their visual representation
My prof. listed 9 axioms of incidence but I will list them group by group since they can be merged:

Every line consists of at least 2 points.
There exists at least one line such that it contains 2 given points.
There exists at most one line such that it contains 2 given different points.

So 1. and 3. are straight forward and easy to imagine, but 2. isn't very clear to me. Let's say there exist some points $A$ and $B$ and ($A \neq B$) and a line $p$ such that $A, B \in p$. Naturally, curiosity would let me find opposite example. Now let's say there's more than one line passing through those 2 points. I don't have formal Hilbert space education, but I think this scenario would belong to that space. Now, the only way I can see this work in Euclidean space is if $A = B$ is true. That's why 'different' is bolded in the 3. statement.

In conclusion, does this mean that 2. only holds true for $A=B$ and then all lines are passing through that one common point of theirs?

Similarly, the following group is for planes:

Every plane contains at least one 'set' of 3 non-collinear points.
There exists at least one plane such that it contains 3 given points.
There exists at most one plane such that it contains 3 given non-collinear points.

To avoid walls of text, I will just get straight to the question but the same idea holds as in the first example.

Would this mean that 5. is represented as 3 collinear points that are contained in the intersection of infinitely many planes? And vice versa, if those 3 points are non-collinear, then every single plane containing them would match with the other planes so there must be only 1 plane in Euclidean space.


If lines were curved then #2 would hold and #3 wouldn't. Remember you don't have a definition of line.

@Intelligentipauca Wouldn't curved lines be used for Hyperbolic geometry (which isn't covered in this course)? That's exactly why I am focusing exclusively on Euclidean geometry where all 3 axioms would be true. My question was, how could I visually represent #2 in Euclidean for a case of there being more than 1 line that go through $A$ and $B$. How I pictured it, was if $A=B$ then it would be true because there would be infinitely many half lines containing the point $A=B$ and that point also being their only intersection point. Could this hold for Euclidean geometry?

If $A\neq B$ was the case, then indeed it would be true ONLY in Hyperbolic geometry but not Euclidean one.

"At least one" doesn't mean "more than one": axiom 2 doesn't preclude the possibility that there is exactly one line between any distinct points $A$ and $B$, and that's exactly what happens under the standard geometry on Euclidean space. In the standard geometry on the surface of a sphere in $3$-space, the lines are great circles and there are infinitely many great circles that join any point with its antipode. So your professor's axiom 3 doesn't hold on the sphere, while axioms 1 and 2 do. But, if you identify each point with its antipode, you get a space called the projective plane that does satisfy axioms 1, 2 and 3.
In both the Euclidean space and the projective plane, axiom 2 still holds when the given points are the same, meaning that you get an infinite family of lines through the point.
Similar comments apply to axioms 4, 5 and 6 although you would need to look at a 3-dimensional hypersphere in $4$-space to get a system of planes that satisfies axioms 4, 5 but not 6, which you could fix by identifying antipodal points to get what is called projective $3$-space.

Yes, your first sentence is exactly my confusion. I imagine "at least one" as $[1, +\infty)$ lines because that's what natural language would lead me to believe, and that's why I was interested in the graphical representation of $(1,+\infty)$ case $(>1)$ in Euclidean geometry. In Hyperbolic, $A\neq B$ is surely true since lines can bend but doing it in Euclidean I think the only possible way is for $A = B$ case where $(1, +\infty)$ lines would have only 1 intersection point ($A=B$).
